# React.createElement: type is invalid on Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm just starting to learn React Native and I tried to do RN on Expo. Now I'm getting this error.

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for 
built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) 
but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the 
file it's defined in.
```

My code is

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, AppRegistry} from 'react-native';

const App = () => (
    <Text>Some Text </Text>
    );


AppRegistry.registerComponent('helloworld', () => App );
```

I worte this cod on the **App.js** file

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Text, AppRegistry} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Hello world!</Text>
    );
  }
}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('helloworld', () => App );
```

Comment: The code I wrote was wrong ? I actually taken that code from a tutorial.

Comment: from which tutorial?

Comment: code which  I shared, is from official documentation https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html