# error: bundling failed: "SyntaxError C:/Program Files/reactt/albums/index.androi d.js: Unexpected token, expected ; (6:8)"

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have code as below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, AppRegistry } from 'react-native';

const App = () => (

  <Text>Boy This is Awsome</Text>
);


AppRegistry.registerComponent('albums', () => App);
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Hi I get this error when i try to run the project in cmd error: bundling failed: "SyntaxError C:/Program Files/reactt/albums/index.androi
d.js: Unexpected token, expected ; (6:8)"

Comment: where did you find this syntax / code? Are following some video or document? Because I have seen this kind of code few hours ago...

Comment: yaes Sir am following some udemy video tutorials. is anything wrong with the code please?

Comment: Same link followed by another OP. Check my answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45365211/react-createelement-type-is-invalid-on-expo/45366041#45366041

Comment: am still getting the same error. what does (6:8) mean at the end of the error message?

Comment: 6 th line and 8 th character, please update your code if you changed

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run this app on your android platform so u should export this file App.js first, In export your current file with this code `export default App;` put this  code at the end of ur file and import your App file in index.android.js file with this code:

```js
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './src/App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Appname', () => App);
```

in my case it the App.js file is in the src folder 
hope this helps you